# How to Upload File through XML Webservice using Java

Tags: java, xml, file-upload

I have read plenty of explanations about how to upload files to a server through XML using C#,  but I have not found how to do the same using Java and have not been able to figure it out at all. I wonder if anybody on you have done this job successfully.

My intention is to do an HTTP posts containing some text values as a caption and description of an image file, then post them and the image file to the web server through XML.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to use Jersey to upload files. Actually, it will enable you to access file content as a **InputStream**. See sample code below:

```
@Consumes("multipart/form-data") 
@POST 
public void post(@FormParam("file") InputStream file) { 
  ... 
}
```

For client side, Jersey can also help you do send HTTP request. A good sample can be found here: http://www.tuple23.com/2010/03/file-upload-using-jersey-client.html

Comment: I need a bit more complete explanations. It seems you meant the code run on server side to receive uploaded file as inputstream, doesnt it? While my mean is to upload file using java app programmatically that runs on client side.

Comment: Sorry, my misunderstood. The answer is now updated with a link to the client side Jersey sample.

Comment: I still can't find where the XML plays the role.

Comment: The requirement is not very clear to me. What does it mean by uploading file through XML?